# Finding all possible values of $z$ given three conditions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

Suppose that $x,y,z$ are positive integers satisfying $x \le y \le z$, and such that the product of all three numbers is twice their sum. What is the sum of all possible values of $z$?

I have only found $2$ sets of positive integers solutions satisfying all conditions, which are $(x, y, z)=(1, 3, 8), (1, 4, 5).$ Would this mean our final solution is $8+5=13?$ I'm not sure if there are any more pairs, or if I did something wrong.

Comment: How did you find these pairs? Just trial and error or some method?

Comment: There is also $(2,2,4)$

Comment: Yea I found them with trial and error. Is there any better method without brute force? Oh wait so our final answer would be $17,$ not $13.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{yz} + \frac{1}{xz} + \frac{1}{xy} \leq \frac{3}{x^2}$.

Therefore, $x^2 \leq 6$ which only leaves $x=1$ and $x=2$

For $x=1$, you get $(x,y,z) = (1,3,8)$ and $(1,4,5)$. I'll leave it to you to prove that these are the only possibilities.

Hint: Use the same technique as above to get an upper bound on $y$ and then try all possible values.

Hint2: $yz = 2 (1+y+z) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{yz} + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{y} \leq \frac{3}{y}$

For $x=2$, you get $(x,y,z) = (2,2,4)$. I'll let you prove that this is the only possibility

So the sum of all $z$ would be 17.